Action handler works in local environment, but doesn't in Docker container
What I expect: when "Add to cart" button is clicked, the items counter in the navbar gets updated.
CartService.cs:
public class CartService
{
    private readonly ILogger<CartService> _logger;
    private readonly IDistributedCache _cache;
    private readonly Guid _cartId;
    private string CartCacheKey => $"Cart:{_cartId}";
    
    public Action? OnCartUpdated { get; set; }
    
    public CartService(ILogger<CartService> logger, IDistributedCache cache, IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _cache = cache;
        var cartIdString = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Request.Cookies["cart-id"] ?? Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        _cartId = Guid.Parse(cartIdString);
    }
    
    public async Task<Dictionary<string,int>> GetCartAsync()
    {
        var cartJson = await _cache.GetStringAsync(CartCacheKey) ?? "{}";
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string,int>>(cartJson) ?? new Dictionary<string, int>();
    }

    public async Task UpdateCartAsync(Dictionary<string, int> cart)
    {
        var cacheEntryOptions = new DistributedCacheEntryOptions
        {
            AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromDays(90)
        };
        var cartJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(cart);
        await _cache.SetStringAsync(CartCacheKey, cartJson, cacheEntryOptions);
        OnCartUpdated?.Invoke();
    }
}

Program.cs:
...
builder.Services.AddScoped<CartService>();
...

ProductPage.razor:
...
@inject CartService CartService

...

@{
    private Dictionary<string,int> Cart { get; set; } = new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Cart = await CartService.GetCartAsync();
    }
...
    private async Task AddToCart(string sku)
    {
        Cart.TryAdd(sku, 1);
        await CartService.UpdateCartAsync(Cart);
    }
...
}

CartIcon.razor:
...
@inject CartService CartService;
...

<div>@_cart.Values.Sum()</div>

...

@code {
    private Dictionary<string,int> _cart= new();

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        CartService.OnCartUpdated += UpdateCart;
        _cart = await CartService.GetCartAsync();
    }

    private void UpdateCart()
    {
        _cart = CartService.GetCartAsync().Result;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
    
    // ReSharper disable once UnusedMember.Global
    public void Dispose()
    {
        CartService.OnCartUpdated -= UpdateCart;
    }
}

It works perfectly when I start app with dotnet run on my host system (Windows 11 x64).
But when I try to run it in a Docker container, it doesn't work. Even links are broken: url in address bar changes but visible content still same until I refresh page with F5.
Docker logs are empty. No errors, no exception, no warnings are shown.
I can't understand why.
